# Crystal Reports, report footer print on a new page

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm having a crystal reports report which is having a report footer append at the end of the report. A report may continue to more than one page,and the footer append to the end of the report.

My problem is sometimes the footer continues to a new page, without any report data. How to make the report footer to stick to the page where report finished without continuing to a new page.

Note: this only happens when the report is having data in a one and finishes on that page. Then the report footer will append to a new page.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how big your report footer is, it may need to print on a new page if there is not enough room left on the current page. Make sure that in Section Expert you don't have any "New Page After" or "New Page Before" boxes checked.

Answer (score 0):

I do right click on my Detail section and then click "Fit Section", and then on properties with same Detail section New Page After set to "False", and the last on the Section Expert, the Report Footer checked the "Print at Bottom of Page"